# Removing extra space at top of the legend in print composer from Python console in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer, qgis-python-console

I have a legend with no title but there is still a large white space above the layer/subgroup title that I would like to remove. I tried using `legend.setTitle("")` and `legend.setStyleFont(QgsLegendStyle.Title, QFont('Arial', 0))` but neither worked. I suspect this is a spacing issue rather than a font issue, but I don't see anything under `setStyle` that looks like it controls spacing.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `rstyle` method of `legend`. You can set spacing using `setMargin` function. Documentation for [`rstyle`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItemLegend.html#a650e74518f755211dc05703a06d50f83) and [`setMargin`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendStyle.html#a5c3ca507174178e100ba6b546c117d95).

```
legend.rstyle(QgsLegendStyle.Title).setMargin(1) # 1 mm
```